# Max sill height for windows as an escape and rescue in a group R-3 occupancy?

Tags: code-compliance, building

Don't have a IBC code book available, assuming it's answered in there. Google is giving me some confusing answers

Answer (score 1):

R-1 = hotels / motels

R-2 = apartments

R-3 = single families, duplex’s, etc. and permanent residents that are NOT R-1, R-2, or R-4

R-4 = Care facilitates of less than 5 and more than 16. (More than 16 are “I” occupancies.)

In R-3 occupancies the “maximum height from the floor shall not be more than 44 inches.”  (Remember, that’s the clear opening, NOT the sill height. The opening could be an inch or so higher than the sill.). (See ICC 1029.3.)

The opening shall be a net 5.7 square feet with the minimum height being 24” and width being 20”, except for grade floor exits shall be a minimum of 5.0 square feet. (ICC 1029.2.)